# Can Titanium code runs in browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I understand that not all the code and functionality are available. However, I am currently in the planing of a new project and there are no document to be found on this aspect.

I want to know once I code in Titanium, is it possible to make a web version for mobile without the application with limited feature and the same code base? (something like touch.facebook.com vs Facebook app)

Thank you very much

Comment: well , i'm not sure i understand well , but it look's like you want to create a responsive website ? in this way ,you don't need to create an "application" , people can use mobile browser to do so.
What would be the difference betwin the web version and the mobile version you want?

Comment: Something like coding a mobile application in titanium, and also compile it to HTML5 and support for users who doesnt have the app install, however with limited capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, Titanium could do that since it also supports MobileWeb. Titanium features:

> Develop native applications for iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Windows, and
>   mobile web through a single code base.

With their [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/titanium-studio/), you can easily build and package your app for MobileWeb.

[image]

But there are a lot of things to consider on developing titanium apps. Here are the few things I've learned along the way:

- Don't use `ImageView`. Use `View` with backgroundImage. If it's an icon, you can make a font for your app. See [how to create an icon font using IcoMoon](http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/25/create-an-icon-font-with-icomoon/).
- [Memory management](http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/)
- Never use borderRadius, borderWidth, borderColor in components within components, as for example a ScrollableView.
- Minimize calling Ti.Platform.[property_name]. Example: instead of always calling `Ti.Platform.osname` to your controllers, you could have put it on you commonjs `var osname = Ti.Platform.osname`, then `exports.getPlatformName = function() { return osname; };`

Here are some few references:

- http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152656/tips-and-tricks-for-memory-management
- http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116867/this-is-a-solution-to-your-memory-woes#answer-203729
- http://www.tidev.io/category/howtos/

Answer (score 1):

Titanium SDK supports iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Tizen and HTML5 platforms. You can read more about that in [their documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-MobileDevelopment). You can limit features in HTML5 app in a code with simple `if()` and reuse most of your codebase.

Comment: so basically I can compile the app to HTML5 application and put it in my web server to support people without the app installed? Thank you :)

Comment: Yes. However, I'm not sure how good is quality of HTML5, so before you dive into it, make small research with some dummy project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web version of the application if you include Mobile Web in the target platforms, when you create the project.

To deploy it on the browser, run the application as Mobile Web.

You may refer the following links for more details.

[Getting Started with Mobile Web](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/getting-started-with-mobile-web/)

[Mobile Web Platform Overview](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Mobile_Web_Platform_Overview)

[Mobile Web Limitations](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Mobile_Web_Limitations)